# proof of matrix identity involving inverse

Tags: matrices, machine-learning

[I'm reading an essay about Properties of Matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfrCz.jpg)

> A useful identity involving matrix inverses is the following
>   $$\begin{align*}(\mathbf{P}^{-1}+\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{R}^{-1}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{T}}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{P}\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{T}}+\mathbf{R})^{-1}&&(\text{C.5})\end{align*}$$
>   which is easily verified by right multiplying both sides by $(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{P}\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{T}}+\mathbf{R})$. Suppose that $\mathbf{P}$ has dimensionality $N\times N$ while $\mathbf{R}$ has dimensionality $M\times M$, so that $\mathbf{B}$ is $M\times N$. Then if $M\ll N$, it will be much cheaper to evaluate the right-hand side of (C.5) than the left-hand side. A special case that sometimes arises is
>   $$\begin{align*}(\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A})^{-1}&&(\text{C.6})\end{align*}$$

This section mentions an easy proof by right multiplication, but how to do it?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: You should be aware that $(A+B)C = (AC+BC)$.  Now, this same idea extends to if things were more complicated.  Now, use the hint and take the proposed identity and multiply both sides by $(BPB^T+R)$ and check for equality after the fact.  Note, by the fact that we are referring to $(BPB^T+R)^{-1}$ in the first place, that implies that what we are multiplying both sides by is invertible and so we can reverse or our logic and be fine, thus proving the desired identity.

Comment: Please cite the essay if you are able. Could you tell us what its name is, and who wrote it?

Answer (score 1):

I will start from the C.5 equality and just do reversible operations. Then you can just start at the end and work backwards. From the equality, perform the indicated right multiplication, obtaining 
$$(P^{-1}+B^{T}R^{-1}B)^{-1}B^{T}R^{-1}(BPB^{T}+R)=PB^{T}$$
Distribute the $R^{-1}$ through the left set of parentheses:
$$(P^{-1}+B^{T}R^{-1}B)^{-1}B^{T}(R^{-1}BPB^{T}+I)=PB^{T}$$
Do the same for $B^{T}$:
$$(P^{-1}+B^{T}R^{-1}B)^{-1}(B^{T}R^{-1}BPB^{T}+B^{T})=PB^{T}$$
If we now right-factor out a $B^{T}$, we get 
$$(P^{-1}+B^{T}R^{-1}B)^{-1}(B^{T}R^{-1}BP+I)B^{T}=PB^{T}$$
One thing we could do now is apply cancellation since we are in a vector space, obtaining
$$(P^{-1}+B^{T}R^{-1}B)^{-1}(B^{T}R^{-1}BP+I)=P$$
Right multiplying by $P^{-1}$, we get 
$$(P^{-1}+B^{T}R^{-1}B)^{-1}(B^{T}R^{-1}B+P^{-1})=I$$
Rearrange the right set of parentheses:
$$(P^{-1}+B^{T}R^{-1}B)^{-1}(P^{-1}+B^{T}R^{-1}B)=I$$
So we get $I=I$.

Comment: but B is a m x n matrix, can we still make BxB^-1 = I or B^T X (B^T)^(-1) =I this way?

Comment: And it is a mistake in after multiply by B^T^-1 ? it should be (B^T R^-1 BP+I) NOT (B^TPBP+I)

Comment: Hm yes it seems that I made that typo, but more critically this does not work since $B$ is mxn. I will correct for this.